# jQuery live not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, prototypejs

The following works in Firefox 3 and IE 7 but not in IE8.

Given this HTML snippet:

```
<li><a href="#" class="remove">remove me</a></li>
```

javascript:

```
jQuery('.remove').live('click', function(e){
            jQuery(this).parent().remove();
        });
```

I wish I had an error message to work with but I don't.

How can I get this to work in IE8?

I should also mention that the anchor tag is being generated by prototype version 1.6.0.

UPDATE: This is a bug in Prototype 1.6.0 and is fixed in 1.6.1 [See Issue](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/563-ie8-adds-a-classname-instead-of-a-class-attr-to-new-elements)

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/nfykQ/ We'll need to see other code to find out more.

Comment: jQuery('a.remove').live('click', function(e){  //try give IE a fuller refference to the tag

Comment: You might want to check that jQuery('.remove') is returning what you are expecting, ie jQuery('.remove').length etc. Also, make sure that another event is not capturing your click event before it reaches the live handler at the top of your document structure.

Comment: If I change the selector to jQuery('a[className="remove"]') it works but for IE8 only.  It seems IE8 uses className instead of class.  Anyone know why?

Comment: className is a property of a DOM element in javascript. class is an HTML attribute. Though they basically represent the same data, they are totally different.

Comment: @jamietre indeed they are totally different.  This is a bug in Prototype 1.6.0 and is fixed in 1.6.1 [See Issue](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/563-ie8-adds-a-classname-instead-of-a-class-attr-to-new-elements)

Comment: @donald.san.jose How does a bug in prototype affect the above code that is using jquery? If that is the answer to your question post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the question, the anchor tag is being generated by Prototype 1.6.0.  This has a bug that generates the class attribute as "className" instead of just "class".  jQuery does not recognize the "className" attribute and therefore my code example fails.  This was identified as a bug in Prototype in their [issue tracking system](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/563-ie8-adds-a-classname-instead-of-a-class-attr-to-new-elements) and was fixed in 1.6.1.