# live() change not working in jquery 1.4.2 on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, jquery

I have been running the following jquery code in IE8 (with jquery 1.4.2). This is working in all other browser like Mozilla, IE9 and so on, but not working in IE8.

Could anyone tell me how can I fix this issue or using the similar code to do the same 'change' function?

```
$('.input-timesheet-type').live('change', function () {
   totalCount($(this).attr('data-teamid'));
});
```

Comment: Any reason to use such an obsolete version ?

Comment: Agree with @dystroy, but I see nothing wrong with this.

Comment: The point is they fix bugs and they adapt to new versions of browsers. It's hard to remember what was the bugs at that time.

Comment: Could it have something to due with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154749/jquery-live-not-working-in-ie8

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624323/does-jqueries-live-work-in-ie8

Comment: Update to jquery 1.9.x and use `.on` - 2.x does not support ie8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although IE8 supports `live()`, `live()` [has some problems](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) using the `change()` event:

> **Possible event values:** click, dblclick, mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, keydown, keypress, keyup
>
> **Currently not supported:** blur, focus, mouseenter, mouseleave, change, submit

Comment: You mean to say jQuery 1.4 doesn't support `change`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.delegate` instead of `.live`, it became available in v1.4.2

[.delegate() in jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Also, .live() does not exist in recent versions of jQuery so, .delegate() will future-proof your code a little better.